Triangle related coordinate geometry question same

Given triangle ABC with $AB$ $=~AC$ and $r_{1} = 2r$ Let $BC~=~a$
Setup the coordinate system in the plane of TriangleABC as follows:
Origin at $B$, positive $X$-axis along $BC$ and positive $Y$-axis on
the A-side of $BC$ .
Find the equations of the incircle, ex-circles and circumcircle.

Any good answers would be appreciated....
This question is same as - Triangle related coordinate geometry question
But reposting as the answer not comprehensible for me

Welcome to math SE. What have you tried?
